# Задача python про циклы и списки

Tags: python, list

Решая задачи на циклы столкнулся с проблемой в строчке с кодом с while.
Выводит ошибку, что индекс списка вне диапазона списка. Помогите пожалуйста

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

s = [a, b, c]

vib = 0
k = 0
while s[vib] != 0:
    if vib < 3:
        s[vib] = s[vib] - 1 
        k += 1
        vib += 1
    elif vib == 3:
        vib = 0
        s1 = s.reverse()
        s1[vib] = s1[vib] - 1
        k += 1
        vib += 1


print(k)
```

Comment: Что значит, когда vib == 3? Последний индекс в массиве — 2

Comment: Добавьте в вопросу суть задания :)

Comment: `s.reverse()` разворачивает сам список, не создает его копию

Comment: `s1 = s[::-1]` создаёт :)

Comment: я к тому, что ошибка идет в том месте где он обращается к `s1[vib]`, а в s1 нет перевернутого списка

Comment: Никак не могу понять, что делает код вообще? Лучшее предположение — что-то вроде `k=a+b+c` =)

Answer (score 1):

индексы в списках начинаются с нуля, и если длина списка `3` до последний элемент находится под индексом `2`, поэтому поменяйте:

`if vib < 3`  на `if vib < 2`

`if vib == 3`  на `if vib == 2`

---

и ещё поменяйте

```
s1 = s.reverse()
```

на

```
s1 = s.copy()
s1.reverse()
```

Comment: так там внутри else сразу устанавливается vib=0, т.е. не идет обращение к 3 элементу списка

Comment: если `vib = 2` то выполняется первый `if` и после этого `vib = 3` цикл `while` начинается заново и `vib = 3`

Comment: Возможно, просто стоит заменить elif на if =)

Comment: @Danis ну и что? внутри цикла попадаем в условие когда `vib==3` там тут же обнуляем `vib`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, чтобы попасть на условие `vib==3`, сначала нужно попасть на `while s[3]!=0:`

Comment: @Danis все согласен, сглупил

Comment: @vp_arth попробовал, но  вывод стал другим

Comment: "Вывод стал другим" Вам известно, каким он должен быть? Делитесь)

Comment: @vp_arth я просто попробовал код с исправлениями в моем коде и просто попробовал поменять `elif` на `if`